# Avoid Duplicate Values in SQL when joining 3 views

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to join 3 tables based ON the primary key column "Color" but I get duplicates whenever there isn't a one-to-one mapping. This is in Snowflake SQL.

Table "Main":

| ID | Color |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Red |
| 2 | yellow |

Table "Fruits":

| Color | Column B | Cost |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Red | Apple | 10.0 |
| Red | Cherry | 5.0 |
| Red | Strawberry | 5.0 |
| Yellow | Banana | 10.0 |
| Yellow | Mango | 10.0 |

Table "Vegetable":

| Color | Column C |
| --- | --- |
| Red | Beetroot |
| Red | Tomato |
| Yellow | Yellow Pepper |

My SQL Query is :

```
select 
 A.ID,
 A."Column A",
 LISTAGG(B."Column B",', ') "All Fruits",
 LISTAGG(B."Cost",', ') "Fruits Cost",
 LISTAGG(C."Column C",', ') "All Vegetables"
FROM
 "Main" A
 INNER JOIN "Fruits" B ON A."Color" = B."Color"
 INNER JOIN "Vegetables" C ON A."Color" = C."Color"
GROUP BY
 A.ID,
 A."Color"
```

Output I Get:

| Color | All Fruits | Fruits Cost | All Vegetables |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Red | Apple, Apple, Cherry, Cherry, Strawberry, Strawberry | 10.0, 10.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0 | Beetroot, Beetroot, Beetroot, Tomato, Tomato, Tomato |
| Yellow | Banana, Mango | 10.0, 10.0 | Yellow Pepper, Yellow Pepper |

The rows contains duplicate values. I want the following:

| Color | All Fruits | Fruits Cost | All Vegetables |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Red | Apple, Cherry, Strawberry | 10.0, 5.0, 5.0 | Beetroot, Tomato |
| Yellow | Banana, Mango | 10.0, 10.0 | Yellow Pepper |

I cannot add `DISTINCT` because this will affect the "Fruits Cost" if different fruits cost the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tables could be aggregated before joining:

```
SELECT  
 A.ID,
 A."Color",
 sub."All Fruits",
 sub."Fruits Cost",
 sub2."All Vegetables"
FROM "Main" A
JOIN (SELECT B."Color", 
            LISTAGG(B."Column B",', ') "All Fruits",
            LISTAGG(B."Cost",', ') "Fruits Cost"
      FROM "Fruits" AS B
      GROUP BY B."Color"
     ) sub ON A."Color" = sub."Color"
JOIN (SELECT C."Color",
             LISTAGG(C."Column C",', ') AS "All Vegetables"
      FROM "Vegetables" C
      GROUP BY C."Color"
      ) sub2 ON A."Color" = sub2."Color"
ORDER BY A.ID;
```

Output:

| ID | Color | All Fruits | Fruits Cost | All Vegetables |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Red | Apple, Cherry, Strawberry | 10.00, 5.00, 5.00 | Beetroot, Tomato |
| 2 | Yellow | Banana, Mango | 10.00, 10.00 | Yellow Pepper |

Answer (score 0):

How about using LISTAGG(DISTINCT… ) ?

**Part 2**

Query each table individually using LISTAGG (within CTEs) and then join the two resultsets together

Comment: This does not work since there is a `Fruits Cost` column. If two different fruits i.e. `Banana` and `Mango` both cost `10`, then DISTINCT will only leave one value (2 Fruits : 1 Cost). But since there are two fruits, there needs to be two cost (2 Fruits : 2 Cost)

Comment: Depending when the “this doesnt work” was added “result 2” is the same answer as Lukasz has given, albeit with CTE’s compared to sub-selects which are interchangeable.